# Vimeo API not working with multiple videos

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo, froogaloop

I'm having some trouble using the Vimeo API with multiple videos.  The code I'm using pauses the

```
<audio id="audio-player" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
<source src="music/peanutbutter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

from playing, but it's only working on the first video iframe.  If I click the Play button on the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th vimeo iframes it unfortunately isn't pausing the audio on the page.  It's probably a simple fix but I'm going crazy trying to figure this out.  Thanks!

```
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

var vimeoPlayer = document.querySelector('iframe');

$f(vimeoPlayer).addEvent('ready', ready);

function ready(player_id) {

    froogaloop = $f(player_id);

    function setupEventListeners() {
        function onPlay() {
            froogaloop.addEvent('play',
            function(){
                $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
                $("#header-button-sound-play").hide();
                $("#header-button-sound-pause").show();
            });
        }

        onPlay();

    }
    setupEventListeners();
}

}) 
</script>

<div id="dwf-trailer" class="content"><iframe id="player_1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/35740045?api=1&player_id=player_1" width="745" height="393" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>

<div id="inkpaper-watch" class="content"><iframe id="player_2" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/33359230?api=1&player_id=player_2" width="745" height="393" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>

<div id="ramon-watch" class="content"><iframe id="player_3" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/44427351?api=1&player_id=player_3" width="745" height="393" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>

<div id="thatsunday-watch" class="content"><iframe id="player_4" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46602515?api=1&player_id=player_4" width="745" height="393" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind!  Figured it out.

Replacing this bit of code

```
$f(vimeoPlayer).addEvent('ready', ready);
```

With this

```
jQuery('iframe').each(function(){
            Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
});
```

fixed the problem!  So the working javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

jQuery('iframe').each(function(){
            Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
});

function ready(player_id) {

    froogaloop = $f(player_id);

    function setupEventListeners() {
        function onPlay() {
            froogaloop.addEvent('play',
            function(){
                $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
                $("#header-button-sound-play").hide();
                $("#header-button-sound-pause").show();
            });
        }

        onPlay();

    }
    setupEventListeners();
}

}) 
</script>
```

Thanks to 
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

for the help!

Comment: You don't need the line
`var vimeoPlayer = document.querySelector('iframe');` anymore.

Comment: I've removed the line @Akash, it's definitely not needed :) Great answer though :)